# Google Drive API order of drive.files.list call

Tags: google-drive-api

- Will the same call always return the results in the same order?
- If I have the `pageToken` X, how long is it valid? Will I be able to navigate in all the files, like they were (ex: without added files) at the time I got this token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results are ordered by modifiedDate by default, the call will not return the results in the same order.

I would not rely on `pageToken` more than a few minutes. You should be able to navigate from the previous state.

Comment: By "modifiedTime", did you mean "modifiedDate"?

Comment: Yes, "modifiedDate" is what I meant. Sorry, fixing the answer.

Comment: Dear Burcu, is there any google page that mentions that results are ordered by modifiedDate?  Ive looked but cant find it on the API reference. For example, given that page tokens expire and I may process thoudands of files, I need to restart searches where I left off (I remember the last processed file's modifiedDate, which will not return in the next search)  Using modifiedDate as a filter in this case only works if the list is really returned always by modifiedDate.